# Error C2248:cannot access private member declared in class

Tags: c++, class, ofstream

I have creates this class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class XLSCreator
{
private:
    ofstream filecontents;
    int fileType;
    int cellNumber;
    int rowsNumber;
public:
    XLSCreator(string);
    ~XLSCreator();
    void createType1File(string, string, string);
    void createType2File(string, string, string, string, string);
    void addNewRow();
    void addData(string);
    void saveFile();
};
```

But When I tried to build it, it gave me this error:

Error   2   error C2248: 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ofstream' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>'

So can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Copy what? what's wrong with the code?

Comment: `std::ofstream` is non-copyable. Presumably, you're trying to copy your class and the default copy-constructor is just memberwise-copying the file stream.

Comment: So I can't used std::ofstream as a member variable?

Comment: You can, evident by how I can compile just your class fine, but you can't rely on the default behaviour for copying it. You'll have to get around that, and how depends on what you want, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you describe could not have come from the code you have provided; your class declaration is fine. It must have come from a different part of your code, in which you attempted to copy your `XLSCreator` class, e.g. by invoking copy-assignment:

```
XLSCreator foo("filename");
XLSCreator bar = foo; //copies foo to create bar
```

The error arises when C++ attempts to generate a [default copy-assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) for your class, which simply calls the copy-assignment operator of each member you've declared. `std::ofstream` is non-copyable, as @chris said in the comments, so when the compiler attempts to call the copy assignment operator of `filecontents`, it finds that it's not allowed to (`operator=` is private within `basic_ofstream`).

In order to fix this, you either need to ensure you never copy an `XLSCreator`, or explicitly define a copy-assignment operator for `XLSCreator` that somehow handles the `filecontents` member without attempting to copy it.

Answer (score -2):

Don't you need to import ofstream? I don't think you can create ofstreams with just iostream and fstream.

Comment: @Basilevs Your comment can be read as saying both "The ofstream header is..." and "The ofstream type is...", so to add: there is no ofstream header. The ofstream type is defined in `<fstream>`.

Comment: @hvd, I don't get your point, but indeed, ofstream is defined in one of the headers included directly or indirectly in <fstream> or in the <fstream> itself. I've just shortened the statement.

Comment: @Basilevs This answer says you need `#include <ofstream>`, and your comment could be read either as saying "no, you don't need that, although it won't do any harm", or as "no, you don't need that, and things will break if you do try it". I was hoping to clarify, but may have failed doing so. :)